# ¿Cómo cancelo la combinación de teclas Ctrl + a (Seleccionar todo) en un Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

¿Cómo puedo cancelar el efecto de la combinación de teclas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> (Seleccionar todo) que tiene el widget `Entry` por defecto??

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

Ventana = Tk()
Label(Ventana,text="Nombre:   ").place(x=0,y=0)
nombre = Entry(Ventana)
nombre.place(x=55,y=0)

def random(self):
    #Como cancelo la accion(seleccionar todo) de ctrl + a ?????
    print("Como cancelo la accion(seleccionar todo) de ctrl + a ?????")

Ventana.bind('<Control-a>', random)
Ventana.mainloop()
```

La función `random` es llamada correctamente, pero además el texto del `Entry` se selecciona como se ha comentado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma general. la forma más simple de evitar que un evento se propague en Tkinter (y con ello desactivar el la función por defecto de la combinación de teclas) es retornar la cadena `"break"` en tu propia callback.

No obstante, siempre hay que tener en cuenta la cadena de propagación de los eventos y el widget al cual enlazamos el evento. En tu caso enlazas el evento <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> a la ventana principal (`Ventana`), por lo que la combinación terminará lanzando la callback `random` sin importar el widget que tenga el foco.

A grandes rasgos, cuando pulsas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> con el foco en el `Entry` el evento primero pasa por la instancia del `Entry` (`nombre`, que no tiene callback asociada). Posteriormente se busca si existen asociaciones a nivel de clase para ese widget (`Entry`) que si existe, en tu caso selecciona todo el texto (esto puede variar entre plataformas). Posteriormente el evento se propaga al widget contenedor (en este caso la ventana principal) y se ejecuta la callback `random`.

Tienes dos opciones muy simples dependiendo de lo que realmente quieras:

- Si deseas que <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> llame a `random` desde cualquier parte de la app pero desactivar la callback por defecto del `Entry`, una opción muy simple es sobreescribir la callback a nivel de clase:

  ```
  import tkinter as tk



  ventana = tk.Tk()
  tk.Label(ventana, text="Nombre:   ").place(x=0, y=0)
  nombre = tk.Entry(ventana)
  nombre.place(x=55, y=0)

  def random_(_):
      print("Como cancelo la accion(seleccionar todo) de ctrl + a ?????")


  def ignore_event(_):
      pass

  ventana.bind_class('Entry', '<Control-a>', ignore_event)
  ventana.bind('<Control-a>', random_)

  ventana.mainloop()
  ```

  o más conciso:

  ```
  ventana.bind_class('Entry', '<Control-a>', lambda _: None)
  ```

  Obviamente esto desactiva la funcionalidad por defecto de <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> para todo `Entry` de la app.
- Si como sospecho, realmente <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> solo debe llamar a `random` cuando el foco está en el `Entry`, entonces simplemente enlaza el evento al mismo y no a al ventana principal:

  ```
  import tkinter as tk



  ventana = tk.Tk()
  tk.Label(ventana, text="Nombre:   ").place(x=0,y=0)
  nombre = tk.Entry(ventana)
  nombre.place(x=55,y=0)

  def random_(_):
      print("Como cancelo la acción(seleccionar todo) de ctrl + a ?????")
      return "break"

  nombre.bind('<Control-a>', random_)
  ventana.mainloop()
  ```

  Si quieres que se aplique a cualquier `Entry`, entonces usa el método `bind_class`:

  ```
  import tkinter as tk



  ventana = tk.Tk()
  tk.Label(ventana, text="Nombre:   ").place(x=0, y=0)
  nombre = tk.Entry(ventana)
  nombre.place(x=55, y=0)

  def random_(_):
      print("Como cancelo la accion(seleccionar todo) de ctrl + a ?????")
      return "break"

  ventana.bind_class('Entry', '<Control-a>', random_)
  ventana.mainloop()
  ```

Algunas observaciones:

- El uso de "wildcard" (`from tkinter import *`) para importar es por lo general una mala práctica.
- No es aconsejable usar el nombre de un módulo de la biblioteca estándar como nombre de variable, clase, función, etc. `random` es un módulo del stdlib, las convenciones dicen que se puede usar `random_` o mejor evitar el nombre si es posible.
- `self` por convención se usa como primer parámetro de los métodos de instancia, haciendo referencia a la propia instancia de la clase. En tu caso la callback lo que recive es el evento, por lo que algo como `def random_(event)` sería más legible. Si no vas a usar el argumento por convención puedes simplemente usar un `_` o `*_` (para ignorar cualquier número de argumentos).